# HP Spectre x360: No sound on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, alsa, hp

Here is my system:

- HP Spectre Laptop x360 - 15t-eb000
- 15.6" diagonal 4K UHD, IPS, micro-edge, WLED-backlit, multitouch-enabled, edge-to-edge, 400 nits (3840 x 2160)
- 1 TB PCIe® NVMe™ M.2 SSD
- Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX 201 (2x2) and Bluetooth® 5 combo (Supporting
  Gigabit file transfer speeds)
- HP TrueVision HD IR Camera with integrated dual array digital
  microphone f2TDB
- 6-cell, 72.9 Wh Li-ion polymer
- Intel® Core™ i7-10750H (2.6 GHz, up to 5 GHz, 12 MB L3 cache, 6
  cores) + NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 Ti with Max-Q design (4 GB) + 16
  GB Memory

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and I have no sound. When I play sound on youtube, I can see the meter moving on the GUI (settings>sound). The sound card name I see is sof-hda-dsp. I made sure all the channels are unmutted in the terminal alsamixer. The sound works fine in the headphones, but not the speakers. I have 30 days to return the laptop, so i'm wondering if I should return it or if the sound can be made to work. I've tried to install Kubuntu and Manjaro, and I have the same issues. I know the speakers work because they work fine in Windows. I'm quite new to Linux so if you can help me out by holding my hand through the process I'd really appreciate it.Thank you.

Comment: Did this come with Ubuntu or did you install it?

Comment: I installed it, I don't think they have a Linux option on this laptop. I've also tried installing Kubuntu and Manjaro. The sound is an issue on both of them. It is not a hardware problem though because the sound works fine on WIndows.